# JPQL OUTER JOIN

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Node {

    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    //getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String message;
    @Column
    private Date timeStamp
    @ManyToOne
    private Node node;
    //getters, setters
}
```

Lets assume now that I have 3 Nodes (N1, N2, N3). N1 and N2 have messages and N3 doesnt have any
What I want as a resulting table is the following:

```
| Node | Last Message |
-----------------------
| N1   | 2014-05-26   |
| N2   | 2014-05-23   |
| N3   |              |
-----------------------
```

So basically I want a JPQL query that returnsthe latest `Message` grouped by each `Node`, 
but also to display the nodes that dont have any messages.
Up till now I have the following query which doesnt give the desired result:

```
select 
    nod.name,
    msg.timeStamp 
from 
    Node nod, 
    Message msg
where
    msg.timeStamp IN 
        (select 
            max(ms.timeStamp) 
         from 
            Message ms 
         group by 
            ms.node)
```

I'm probably missing a join somewhere up there but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL doesn't allow join without relations defined, but allows right outer join so you can do your query like this;

```
select 
    nod.name,
    Max(msg.timeStamp) 
from 
    Message msg
right join
    msg.node nod
group by 
    nod.name;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah was still using jpa 2.0 and was getting an IDE error for using the right join. Upgraded to 2.1 and it works :)

Comment: Oh, great you figure it. I forget to mention that. Sry.